# ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'

Tags: mysql

I am looking for some help regarding the error I am receiving in MySQL. I am fairly new to MySQL. I have the following table:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| date         | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| time         | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| messure      | decimal(9,2) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| inject_units | decimal(9,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------
```

I am using the below query to insert data into the table

```
INSERT INTO sugar_levels (date, time, messure, inject_units) VALUES ('2017-08-22',STR_TO_DATE('2017-08-22 05:50:00', 'Y%-m%-d% H%:m%:s', '11.7', '12'));
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'
```

Please help as this it might be a simple syntax error.

Comment: You miss the `%` sign after `H%:m%:s` and also the `)`

Answer (score 1):

3 errors:

First `%` sign must be before the letters
Second missing `%`sign before the second placeholder
Third The bracket is at wrong place:

```
INSERT INTO sugar_levels (date, time, messure, inject_units) 
 VALUES ('2017-08-22',STR_TO_DATE('2017-08-22 05:50:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'), '11.7', '12');
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed these issues now getting the following: ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '2017-08-22 05:50:00' for function str_to_date